# Understanding "RangeError: maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: node.js, socket.io, lodash, winston

I'm relatively new to Node.JS, I am developing an online game, when I stumbled across this error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er: // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeeded
```

The errors didn't show where my code breaks/ends, and I do some simple debugging using `console.log`, and I know somehow my program ended on:

```
game.on('end', function (data) {
    winston.log('info', 'Game %s ended', game.name); // printed
    console.log("test - A");                   // this is printed
    io.to(room.name).emit('game ended', data); // <- I think this one breaks
    console.log("test - B");                   // this is NOT printed
});
```

(`game` is a game module I've written myself)
Right now I am really confused.
Tried setting `--max-stack-size=100000` but the error still happened.

My program has becoming more complex lately.
It uses Socket.IO, Lodash, Winston.
I use many Lodash's function, especially `_.forEach`.

Is the error because of Socket.IO ? Or Lodash ?
Or maybe because I am not used to asynchronous programming ?
Is there any detailed reason behind this error ?
How can I ensure that this error won't happen again ?

Comment: What's in `data`? That error is usually a sign of an infinite loop or an unclosed thread, etc.

Comment: I bet @Antiga is right.  If I recall correctly, node.js isn't very smart about serializing objects with reference cycles to JSON (and socket.io uses JSON for serialization).

Comment: Actually, I take that back.  What node version are you using?  socket.io version?  On node v0.10.25, JSON.stringify is reasonably smart about circular references.

Comment: Yes, you're right, `data` contains circular references. I think it is what caused the problem. I am using node version `0.10.31`. So, node.js can't handle the circular reference?

Answer (score 2):

A circular reference will create errors because it will not evaluate to a declared value (number, string, boolean), nor to 'undefined'. Instead, the circular reference will be followed in an infinite loop, and without a mechanism to stop it the program routine will consume available memory and can throw errors and crash. Avoid circular references like the plague.

In your code-- if `data` references itself, then this is certainly what is causing the maximum call stack size to be exceeded.